# AWS Neptune /system Bad Route Connection Error

Tags: amazon-neptune

I am trying to reset my Neptune instance following the documentation provided,

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/resetting-your-graph-data-in-amazon-neptune-in-seconds/
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/manage-console-fast-reset.html

When I try these approach to `awscurl`, I am getting BadRequestException error

```
{"requestId":"21cd6d80-some-more-code-25566575a4ba","code":"BadRequestException","detailedMessage":"Bad route: /system"}
```

This was my `awscurl`

```
awscurl -X POST --access_key ACCESS_KEY --secret_key SECRET_KEY --service  neptune-db "https://neptunedbinstance-somecode.somemorecode.us-east-2.neptune.amazonaws.com:8182/system" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' --region us-east-2 -d '{ "action" : "initiateDatabaseReset" }'
```

Comment: What version of Neptune are you running?  This feature was added in 1.0.4.0.

Comment: @Taylor Riggan can I get doc reference to that version update log. If you have it. "dbEngineVersion":"1.0.2.2.R5" I have this version

Comment: I have filed a case internally to update our documentation. We presently don't have it documented that 1.0.4.0 is the minimum version required, yet that is the case.  1.0.4.0 was released on 2020-10-12.  We publicly announced the Fast Reset feature via blog post on 2020-12-17:  https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/resetting-your-graph-data-in-amazon-neptune-in-seconds/   The blog post references the version dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Adding an answer in case others find this question.

The fast reset feature requires that the Neptune engine version needs to be 1.0.4.0 or later. There is a related [blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/resetting-your-graph-data-in-amazon-neptune-in-seconds/) that describes the feature in detail.